# Delphi: generate the hash/checksum of a TObject with BobJenkinsHash

Tags: delphi

I have this function that generate a checksum of a `TStream` with [BobJenkinsHash](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Generics.Defaults.BobJenkinsHash):

```
function GetStreamHashBobJenkins(Stream: TStream): String;
var
   Hash:   THashBobJenkins;
   Readed: Integer;
   Buffer: PByte;
   BufLen: Integer;
begin
   Hash   := THashBobJenkins.Create;
   BufLen := 16 * 1024;
   Buffer := AllocMem(BufLen);
   try
      Stream.Seek(0, 0);
      while Stream.Position < Stream.Size do begin
         Readed := Stream.Read(Buffer^, BufLen);
         if Readed > 0 then begin
            Hash.update(Buffer^, Readed);
         end;
      end;
      Stream.Seek(0, 0);
   finally
      FreeMem(Buffer)
   end;
   Result := Hash.HashAsString;
end;
```

from the docwiki of [System.Generics.Defaults.BobJenkinsHash](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Generics.Defaults.BobJenkinsHash) i read:

> BobJenkinsHash is used to generate the hash code of a memory block.

The wiki seem talk about a generic "memory block", is possible generate the checksum of a generic `TObject`?

Comment: Not easy in general. It's a bit like the deep copy problem. Ask yourself how reference tree structures will be handled?

Comment: Your `while` loop is inefficient for non memory streams, like `TFileSteam`. You don't need to check the `Position` manually at all, just break the loop when `Read` reaches EOF: `Stream.Position := 0; repeat Readed := Stream.Read(Buffer^, BufLen); if Readed < 1 then Break; Hash.update(Buffer^, Readed); until False;` And you don't need `AllocMem()` and `FreeMem()` if you use a dynamic array instead.